# Add new column in Cucumber overview report

Tags: selenium, cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java

Our cucmber-overview report looks like below.

[image]

We want to add a new column to this report with name "Author" of the script.

We are using selenium,Java and gherkin for automation.

Can anyone help ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's an easy way to add this data during the test execution itself, but as the report is an HTML file, then you can surely manipulate it after the fact.
You'd probably need to save your additional information during the test execution in a separate file or database. Then, in a separate process after the test execution completes and the original report is generated, you should read this data and add it to the HTML file using jsoup or something similar.